# Select and update with conditional calculations in a Postgres database

Tags: python, sql, database, select, psycopg2

I have a Postgres table named rain_tanks as shown below:

```
 id   hour     rain    demand    current_volume  unmet_demand
 1    00:00    4.0     2.0       2               0.0
 2    00:10    3.0     4.0       [null]          [null]
 3    00:20    1.0     6.0       [null]          [null]
 4    00:30    7.0     3.0       [null]          [null]
```

I would like to do this calculations and update current_volume and unmet_demand columns (this code is just to show what needs to be done. I would like to do it without using function or code lines in Python):

```
a = lag(current_volume) + rain - demand
if a < 0: 
    unmet_demand = current_volume    
    current_volume = 0
else:
    unmet_demand = 0
    current_volume = a
```

Expected table:

```
 id   hour     rain    demand    current_volume  unmet_demand
 1    00:00    4.0     2.0       2               0
 2    00:10    3.0     4.0       1               0
 3    00:20    1.0     6.0       0               -4
 4    00:30    7.0     3.0       4               0
```

I guess what I need is to first SELECT and the UPDATE the columns. I tried the following for the SELECT but its not working:

```
import psycopg2 as p
conn = p.connect("dbname = 'test' user = 'postgres' password = 'pass' host = 'localhost'")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT Id,rain,demand,current_volume,unmet_demand, 
                      CASE WHEN (rain - demand + lag(current_volume) over(
                                 order by Id)) >= 0 
                           THEN (rain - demand + lag(current_volume) over(
                                 order by Id)) ELSE 0 END 
               FROM rain_tanks ORDER BY Id""")
```

### Edit

This is an additional question related to performance. The reason I decided to do these calculations in a Postgres database was to see whether there is a speed improvement in comparison to using Numpy arrays in Python. I have around 10 million points for the rain and demand columns and the answer provided here takes longer than an equivalent python function over Numpy arrays of rain and demand. Is there still space to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: what does *not working* mean?

Comment: It doesnt give me the correct results.

Comment: so you have these values for the first row..and want to get it for the others?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the first row it is assumed that the previous current_volume was zero. So 4 - 2 = 2. the second row needs to know how much is the current_volume in the previous row and the rain and demand in the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a recursive cte to get the desired result. As each row depends on the previous calculation which can't be acheived with `lag`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(id,rain,demand,new_current_volume,new_unmet_demand) as 
(SELECT Id,rain,demand
 ,case when rain-demand <0 then 0 else rain-demand end as new_current_volume
 ,case when rain-demand <0 then rain-demand else 0 end as new_unmet_demand
 FROM rain_tanks
 WHERE id = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT r2.Id,r2.rain,r2.demand
 ,case when r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand <0 then 0 else r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand end
 ,case when r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand <0 then r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand else 0 end
 FROM cte r1
 JOIN rain_tanks r2 ON r2.id=r1.id+1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/NWYDC53828)

EDIT:

To `update` the table based on the newly calculated values, include 2 `null` columns with the column names from the table, along with the calculated ones. Then you can `update` them with these calculations after the cte.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(id,rain,demand,current_volume,unmet_demand,new_current_volume,new_unmet_demand) as 
(SELECT Id,rain,demand,null,null
 ,case when rain-demand <0 then 0 else rain-demand end as new_current_volume
 ,case when rain-demand <0 then rain-demand else 0 end as new_unmet_demand
 FROM rain_tanks
 WHERE id = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT r2.Id,r2.rain,r2.demand,null,null
 ,case when r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand <0 then 0 else r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand end
 ,case when r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand <0 then r1.new_current_volume+r2.rain-r2.demand else 0 end
 FROM cte r1
 JOIN rain_tanks r2 ON r2.id=r1.id+1
)
UPDATE rain_tanks r
SET current_volume=c.new_current_volume
   ,unmet_demand=c.new_unmet_demand
FROM cte c
WHERE r.id=c.id;
```

Comment: You are right, I wasn't expecting this! Its working perfectly.

Comment: Just a quick question. What is the best method to save the results (preferably in the same table)?

Comment: you mean updating the table?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write the result of the calculations (new_current_volume and new_unmet_demand) into two columns.